# setting markers for the tutorials

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am implementing [this](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html) tutorial . please guide is there any proper site from where i can get the latitude and longitude , i have found many but most of them providing some specific area latitude and longitude  plus i would like to know is there any method for setting up the markers other then latitude and longitude , by location name for this tutorial

for example

```
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Frankie Johnnie & Luigo Too','939 W El Camino Real, Mountain View, CA','37.386339','-122.085823');
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`) VALUES ('Amici\'s East Coast Pizzeria','790 Castro St, Mountain View, CA','37.38714','-122.083235');
```

can be replaced by

```
INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `address`)
```

or this would be the best case that admin can directly set a marker on the page and it stores lat and longi of the position

please guide . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have longitude and latitude to show something on the map.

Of course there are ways to geocode names and places, but in the backend that translates to coordinates as well. Especially in the tutorial case, there are no real places i suspect - only dummy data that will not be geocodeable.